# Generalize integral template parameters

Tags: c++, templates

Is there a way to generalize an integral template parameter so that it supports e.g. `int` and `std::size_t`. Here is non-compiling example of what I have in mind. Is there a way to implement the function `f` without adding a copy of it that takes `std::size_t` as a parameter?

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>

template <int N>
struct foo {
    static constexpr int n = N;
    int a[N];
};

template <std::size_t N>
struct bar {
    static constexpr int n = N;
    float a[N];
};

template <template<int> typename T, int N>
void f(T<N> t) {
    std::cout << T<N>::n << " - " << N << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    bar<10> B;
    foo<20> F;

    f(B);
    f(F);
}
```

Comment: If you can use C++20 features, the [`std::integral`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concepts/integral) concept would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `c++17` you can use `auto` for non-type template parameters.

```
template <template<auto> typename T, auto N>
...
```

Comment: This is good until you don't need integral specific. Anyway, then you can use `template<auto>` and then write specific for integral like use `std::is_integral`

Comment: @NejcGalof Sure. If you're using c++17 a `static_assert` or SFINAE will work. With `c++20` a concept is probably better.

Answer (score 2):

In C++17, this is a simple as

```
template <template <auto> typename T, auto N>
void f(T<N> ) { }
```